# Understanding the differences / changes between .Net 4.6 and 4.6.2

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-4.6

This may not be the right place for this question, if so please let me know and I shall remove it.

I plan on upgrading my WinForms application from .Net 4 Framework to 4.6 or 4.6.2.

> -Which would be the way to go ?
>   -Which is the version that is more stable and supported ?
>   -What are the advantages of one over the other ?

.Net 4 is no longer supported (?) and that is the driving factor for the upgrade. Plus, I would like all my external WebClient calls from the WinForms app to use TLS 1.2 which I believe is available with 4.6 and later. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: .NET 4 isn't supported, the earliest supported version is 4.5.2  TLS was added in 4.5.2 too. The important change though is `async/await`, not TLS1.2. TLS is the "what have you been waiting for?" change. `async/await` is the Warp Speed 6 change.

Comment: As for 4.6 vs 4.6.2 - *why* pick the old version? It's not like you can *force* the client to use 4.6 - 4.6.2 is a binary replacement for all 4.x versions. Your clients will probably be running 4.6.2, eg as a result of a Windows Update or another application installation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thanks for the response. Yes, TLS1.2 has been available since 4.5.2 and that would not be the only change triggering this update. My question about the 4.6 and 4.6.2 is to understand which one is better supported and has lesser known critical bugs.

Comment: just check the release notes. 4.6 bug fixes were deployed in 4.6.1 and 4.6.2 so ...

Comment: Another import factor is operating system support. 4.6 supports Vista and newer, 4.6.1 supports Windows 7 and newer, 4.6.2 does not support Windows 8 but is still supported on Windows 7, 8.1 and 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First: changes between 4.6 and 4.6.2

`.NET 4.6.2` mostly consists of fixes for the bugs that were identified.

For full list of changes in 4.6.2 you can refer to the link below

https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net462/dotnet462-changes.md

Support has already been ended for the versions `4, 4.5 and 4.5.1` while `3.5, 4.5.2` are still being supported.

Newer versions generally comes with more features but there could be bugs which get fixed in later versions of the product.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Makes sense. I did go through the release notes of 4.6.2 and made sure it has everything I needed. I was just wondering with 4.6.2 being the most recent release, is it stable or does it have some known outstanding bugs. I went through the repo to look for outstanding open issues but they were inconclusive.